# How to get all email type field values

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, sosl, dynamic-sosl

How to get all email type field values in a salesforce lead record from a record id in apex class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all the email type field of any object using the describe call.

```
String strEmailFiels = '';
for(Schema.SObjectField field : Lead.getSobjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().values())
{
    if(Schema.DisplayType.EMAIL == field.getDescribe().getType())
        strEmailFiels += ', ' + field.getDescribe().getName();

}
strEmailFiels = strEmailFiels.removeStart(',');
system.debug('======strEmailFiels======='+strEmailFiels);
```

Then you can use those email type fields in soql query

Comment: Happy to help you :)